# Trying to add a property to an object, but it removes all previous instead of adding to it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cypress

I have this main function that writes a log, it addds the arg, to an existing object called logContent:

```
function printToLog(arg) {
  LogContent = { ...LogContent, ...arg };
  cy.writeFile(filepath, LogContent);
}
```

This function is used inside of other functions like this one that checks if it is a step or a page:

```
function printStepToLog(page, step) {
  if (step) {
    printToLog({
      [`${page}`]: {
        ...LogContent[`${page}`],
        [`${step}`]: "passed"
      }
    });
  } else {
    printToLog({
      [`${page}`]: "passed"
    });
  }
}
```

There is a bigger function that checks for warning on the page and if there are it adds them to the log:

```
function logProgress(page, step) {
  cy.wait(800); //give time to let validaiton run
  
  getAndLog(".block-content").within(form => {
    let errors = form.find(".mat-error");
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
      [...errors].forEach((error, i) => {
        LogContent = {
          ...LogContent,
          [`${page}`]: {
            ...LogContent[`${page}`],
            [`${step}`]: "failed"
          },
          error: { ...LogContent.error, [`err${i}`]: error.innerText }
        };
      });
      cy.writeFile(filepath, LogContent);
    } else {
      printStepToLog(page, step);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that this function getAndLog... doesnt just add to the object, it completely overwrites the obj.. so if it fails, the rest of the infos like the passed pages and steps are gone.

```
function getAndLog(identifier, altText) {
  printToLog({ currentGet: { [altText || identifier]: "not found" } });
  cy.get(identifier)
  printToLog({ currentGet: { [altText || identifier]: "found" } });
  return cy.get(identifier)
}
```

I am usng the "getAndLog" function instead of cy.get to get elements, as I want to log whats being searched for, and if it was found.

But this makes the log contents be replaced with just the current prop.

Cant see why it overwrites everything instead of just adding the "current" property if, on the "printToLog" which is being used inside the "getAndLog" function,  its adding the LogContent content by spreading it?

Answer (score 0):

By default the writeFile function overwrites the file (flag 'w'). Just change the flag as in this example:

```
cy.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello World', { flag: 'a+' })
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Append-contents-to-the-end-of-a-file)